# ruby framework method -> what's going on here?

Tags: ruby, syntax

```
def partial(template, *args)
  options = args.extract_options!
  options.merge!(:layout => false)
  if collection = options.delete(:collection) then
    collection.inject([]) do |buffer, member|
      buffer << erb(template, options.merge(:layout =>
      false, :locals => {template.to_sym => member}))
    end.join("\n")
  else
    erb(template, options)
  end
end
```

This method has no docs. It seems to be some way of letting you add additional features to partial rendering in an erb template.

How does this Ruby code work?

I don't care as much about the role this plays in a web framework. I just would like to understand what's going on in terms of Ruby syntax.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It works much like doing `render :partial` in Rails — it takes a partial and a list of options (e.g. a collection of objects to render using the partial) and renders the partial with those options. Except this method appears to have ERb hardcoded in. If this is from Rails, I think this must be a very old method that isn't meant for use but hasn't yet been removed (maybe for compatibility with something or another).

The `options.merge!(:layout => false)` is effectively like doing `options[:layout] = false`.

`options.delete(:collection)` deletes the entry for ":collection" from the options hash and returns it if it exists. If there wasn't a collection entry, it returns nil, so the associated if-block won't run. If there is a collection, it renders the partial for each element of the collection and returns the accumulated result of rendering all of them. If there is not a collection, it just renders the partial with the options specified.

Comment: Wow. What a great explanation. Thank you. Actually it's not for Rails. Someone wrote this as an extension for Sinatra because Sinatra has minimal features for partials. I just couldn't figure out what it was adding. But your explanation makes sense. I think the main feature is to be able to render multiple times for a collection - like maybe a collection of comments or orders. Just one question. You said "options.merge!(:layout => false) is effectively like doing options[:layout] = false." Does that mean it's always setting :layout to 'false'? Kind of like setting a default value to be re-set?

Comment: Yes, it always sets options[:layout] to false, because you don't want a partial wrapped with a layout.

Answer (score 0):

To understand this, you need to understand the docs on these methods:

- extract_options!
- Enumerable/Array: merge, merge!, inject, join, delete

Once you understand those, there's nothing tricky about the syntax here. You should be able to read it straight through.

Something in particular?